# password crypt authentication not supported error when connecting postgreSQL and automation anywhere

Tags: postgresql, automation, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, automationanywhere

I am trying to connect Automation anywhere with postgreSQL For that I have created with all three below entries[image]

Earlier , I was getting this error "**test connection failed error in initializing provider. the specified dsn contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and application postgresql**" when i was trying to connect 32 bit Automation anywhere to 64bit DNS, but after created 32 bit DNS and i am getting this error "**password crypt authentication not supported**".

Can anyone help me resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the insecure `crypt` password authentication method has been retired in PostgreSQL 8.4 in 2009.

I think you should use a less antique version of the ODBC driver.